# check if file exist in folder

Tags: php, file-exists

My script:

```
$secret = check_input($_GET['secret']);
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    if (isset($secret) || !empty($secret)) {
        if (file_exists(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $secret)) {
            unlink(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $secret);
            $trusted = 'yes';
        } else {
            $trusted = 'no';
        }
    }
//$_POST['register'] register details...
}
```

1. Is there another way to do it (simplier, etc.)?
2. If `$secret` doesn't exist in the `/codes/` folder, it produces `Warning: unlink Is a directory` How to get rid of that?
3. Why `$trusted` always gives `yes` even if the file doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To delete a directory, you should be using [`rmdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) instead of [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

```
$secret = check_input($_GET['secret']);
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    if (!empty($secret)) {
        if(file_exists(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $secret)) {
            rmdir(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $secret);
            $trusted = 'yes';
        } else {
            $trusted = 'no';
        }
    }
    //$_POST['register'] register details...
}
```

Although, there is a serious security risk here! If your `check_input()` does not properly sanitize `$secret`, you could `rmdir('/intl/codes/../')` which is the same as deleting /intl/.
 Try something like this:

```
$allowed = ROOT. '/intl/codes/';
$path = realpath($allowed . check_input($_GET['secret']));

if(strpos($path, $allowed) === 0) {  //Check that $path is within allowed directory
    if(is_dir($path)) {
        rmdir($path);
    } else if(file_exists($path)) {
        unlink($path);
    } else {
        echo "File/folder not found";
    }
} else {
    echo "Untrusted user tried to delete outside of allowed directory";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use just `if (!empty($secret))` - [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) returns `TRUE` for `NULL` value as well.
2. Use `if (file_exists(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $secret) && !is_dir(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $secret))` to check if your file is not a directory and get rid of that warning. If you still wanna remove the directory, use [`rmdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) function.
3. `file_exists()` returns `TRUE` for directories as well. So, you should also check if the argument is a directory with [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) , as i said before.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (file_exists(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $secret)) {
        unlink(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $secret);
        $trusted = 'yes';
    } else {
        $trusted = 'no';
    }
```

> Is there another way to do it (more simplier, etc.)?

No, Only way is to use `file_exists`

> If $secret doesn't exist in /codes/ folder, it produce Warning: unlink Is a directory How get rid of of that?

It seems `$secret` points to a directory. The execution path reaches to `unlink` because `if` part returns true. So it exists. To delete a directory use `rmdir()`

> Why $trusted always give's yes even if file doesn't exist ?

Because `unlink` deletes it and sets `$trusted` to `yes`. When you search after deletion you see it doesn't exist but `$trusted` contains `yes`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your `$secret` is an empty string, but it's passing your `isset()` test.
So the **directory** `ROOT . '/intl/codes/'` does exist (thus passing `file_exists()` check), but you can't `unlink()` the directory (neither is it your intention here).

Make sure that you have something non-empty in `$_GET['secret']` and verify your `check_input()` function.

P.S. You probably should remove `isset($secret)` part of the condition. `!empty($secret)` is enough here and it will fix your script.

Answer (score 1):

as stated by php documentation about [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php):

```
Checks whether a file or directory exists
```

My only guess for your question #3 is: You check if file exists and it does. Only, it's not file, it's directory.

as for #2, also as stated by the error message, you can do something like this:

$file_to_check = ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $secret;

```
if (file_exists($file_to_check)) {
    if( !is_dir( $file_to_check ) )
        unlink($file_to_check);
    else
        rmdir( $file_to_check );
    $trusted = 'yes';
}
```

and for your #1 question, you might one to do something like this:

```
$secret = input_get($_GET['secret']);
if(isset($_POST['register']) && !empty($secret)) {

    $file_to_check = ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $secret;
    if (file_exists($file_to_check)) {
        if( !is_dir( $file_to_check ) )
            unlink($file_to_check);
        else
            rmdir( $file_to_check );
        $trusted = 'yes';
    } else {
        $trusted = 'no';
    }
}

function input_get($key, $default = ""){

    if(!isset($_GET[$key])){
        return $default;
    } else {
        //do input cleanup first, if you want
        return $_GET[$key];
    }
}
```

A little bit of explanation:

1. I don't know what `check_input()` does, so I created wrapper function for `$_GET[]` called `input_get()`. It removes the need to do `isset()` and also fill in the default value.
2. I put `ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $secret;` into variable `$file_to_check` so that you don't have to type it again and again.